# Get All Combinations of Splitting a String in 3 Sub Strings in Python

Tags: python, arrays, split

Here is the string :

```
st = 'abcdfdedf'
```

I want to split the string in 3 sub string and get all the combinations as such:

```
result = [['abc','dfd','edf'],['abcd','f','dedf'], ...]
```

Note: Order is not important here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand the question, it is a simple matter of keeping track of the two split positions. For example:

```
from pprint import pprint

st = 'abcdfdedf'

n = len(st)
splits = []
for i in range(1, n-1):
    for j in range(i+1, n):
        splits.append([st[0:i], st[i:j], st[j:]])
pprint(splits)
```

which results in

```
[['a', 'b', 'cdfdedf'],
 ['a', 'bc', 'dfdedf'],
 ['a', 'bcd', 'fdedf'],
 ['a', 'bcdf', 'dedf'],
 ['a', 'bcdfd', 'edf'],
 ['a', 'bcdfde', 'df'],
 ['a', 'bcdfded', 'f'],
 ['ab', 'c', 'dfdedf'],
 ['ab', 'cd', 'fdedf'],
 ['ab', 'cdf', 'dedf'],
 ['ab', 'cdfd', 'edf'],
 ['ab', 'cdfde', 'df'],
 ['ab', 'cdfded', 'f'],
 ['abc', 'd', 'fdedf'],
 ['abc', 'df', 'dedf'],
 ['abc', 'dfd', 'edf'],
 ['abc', 'dfde', 'df'],
 ['abc', 'dfded', 'f'],
 ['abcd', 'f', 'dedf'],
 ['abcd', 'fd', 'edf'],
 ['abcd', 'fde', 'df'],
 ['abcd', 'fded', 'f'],
 ['abcdf', 'd', 'edf'],
 ['abcdf', 'de', 'df'],
 ['abcdf', 'ded', 'f'],
 ['abcdfd', 'e', 'df'],
 ['abcdfd', 'ed', 'f'],
 ['abcdfde', 'd', 'f']]
```